# Inspect Element data in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, mechanize

i am trying to get the inspect element data for the below link.

http://114.255.167.200:8092/image/imageAction.do?method=show&q=a&serverid=100&view=1&bussinessid=2015011200007001&sgbh=2015011200007&afsj=201408&user=201105#pos=1

I tried in different packages in python like using the beautifulsoup,mechanize and selenium methods. but all are giving the view source data it is completely different from inspect element data. can anyone help me how to get the inspect element data for the link. basically i want to get the image from the link given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://114.255.167.200:8092/image/imageAjaxAction.do?_=1481194840797&q=a&pos=0&count=48&f=1&serverid=100&bussinessid=2015011200007001
```

check this page, this is where the picture data came from , you can change the url to get the data you need.

Comment: How did you get this info. as i need to check the same data for different cases.

Comment: Thanks  宏杰李. It helped me a lot.

Comment: for the link below                                                                                       https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=771013696&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=true                   where I can get the images location.    I tried the same way to check network tab but I am not able to get anything.

Comment: @ 宏杰李 Can you please help me on this issue.